# Making image fit using bootstrap

Tags: html, angular, image-resizing

I know this question must sound familiar, and I can see loads of people asking similar questions but none of the answers are working for me. Everyone has a fairly specific need. I want to understand the basics and I can work out the rest.

I have a simple angular/bootstrap web page. I have made a carousel component and I want to ensure the user always sees the entire image.  I have seen lots of answers which suggest img-fluid, max-with, max-height etc., but nothing's working for me. It's sort-of working for landscape images but not for portrait images.  I need it to always show the whole image regardless.

Here is the basic app component:

```
<app-nav-menu ></app-nav-menu>

<div style="padding:10px">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

The router-outlet goes to this "about-us" component:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <app-carousel [slides]="slides"></app-carousel>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the carousel component looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div>
                <img [src]="slide.src">
                <p style="position: absolute;  top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">
                    {{slide.text}}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see it's really simple.  Right now there is no styling other than the little bit in the p tag which is to center the text in the image.  This is not working properly now, because I think I've lost the container whilst trying out different solutions.  I don't like CSS because I'm not used to them and I like to see the styles where they belong so I can understand better. But feel free to suggest a CSS solution if necessary.
So the question is simple: how can I make the image always fit the screen and not spill downwards?
Thanks

Comment: The image must not be distorted - the aspect ratio must remain true to the original image. Blank spaces top/bottom or left/right in order to fit are ok.  Also ignore class="container", or that whole div - it's a hangover from centering the text, I'll have to do that again.

Comment: Did you try to add a image as a cover?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the object-fit property?

object-fit: cover;

If your image aspect ration is good, it shows the entire image.

object-fit: contain:

This shows the entire image, but if the aspect ratio is not good, it shows blank spaces around the image.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks SureN.
I tried both of these but they didn't work.  Perhaps they would do if I knew how to use them better.
In the end the following more or less worked for me, in the img tag:

```
style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100vh; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"
```

It's not perfect but it'll do for now!